# Can I travel to Canada with a Valid Visa on a Valid Passport along with Renewed Passport?

Tags: visas, canada, passport-renewals

I just got my Canada Visa with my current passport which expires on 12/25/2018. I'm planning to travel to Canada on 05/19/2018 and I'm thinking of renewing my passport now, is it okay to renew now and travel with Valid Visa on a Valid Passport along with Renewed Passport? or do I have to renew my Passport after my Canada Visit?

Comment: Nope, other question was about VISA on an expired Passport and a renewed Passport, but mine is about  VISA on an Valid Passport and a renewed Passport

Comment: As soon as you renew your passport, your old passport becomes invalidated, so the answer is the same.

Comment: As Jim said. if you renew, your old one usually is invalidated.